# How use ACRA system to detect crashes in android?

Tags: android, acra

i want to use ACRA to call a certain web service to my server to report a crash in android app , thus my server is not integrated with any thing to ACRA system i just want to call my own web service when crash is happened and get crash data from ACRA and send it with my web service parameters .Is it possible ? thanks

```
   @ReportsCrashes(
    formUri = "http://myserver/ErrorLogging/Logger.svc",
    reportType = HttpSender.Type.JSON,
    httpMethod = HttpSender.Method.POST,
    formUriBasicAuthLogin = "serverusername",
    formUriBasicAuthPassword = "serverpass",
    mode = ReportingInteractionMode.DIALOG,
    resToastText = R.string.message
```

Comment: they've really nice docs, have you read it? https://github.com/ACRA/acra/wiki/BasicSetup

Comment: @AshishRanjan thanks , i already read this doc and integrated ACRA to my app successfully and i could send email with crash report ,but i need to call a service with crash data to my server side

Comment: `ACRA` will send a `JSON` data report to whatever `url` you'll provide in the `formUri` using the HTTP method that you've configured(`POST` in this case), so you just need to configure your server to receive and save the Json report correctly.

Comment: you can use `Acralyzer` to visualize your crash report data, its really nice and simple to use : https://github.com/ACRA/acralyzer/wiki

Comment: Why you don't use Firebase ? it's very powerful system and it's easily integrate with your app

Comment: `Is it possible ?` yes

Comment: I think Firebase for crash reporting is in beta and I am not sure if it's free this service (I mean the crash reporting). I'm using Acralyzer with Cloudant and, as long as you use it for personal testing so no thousands and thousands of calls, it's free.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on you using svc instead of the official backend, I'm going to take a guess and say you have client side(app) under control and what you need, is something to recieve the crashes. Now, this really depends on your hosting.
[Full list here](https://github.com/ACRA/acra/wiki/Backends)

As long as you can run PHP files, you can use PHP hosting files(probably the reason there are so many of them). If you cannot do any of the above, @F43nd1r's answer is the best way to go. Most of the above backends does not need to implement a new sender, as they use the implemented sender.

Answer (score 0):

If your server can't handle one of the Standard options (Form or JSON, POST or PUT), you can create your own `ReportSender`. You then have to supply ACRA with a `ReportSenderFactory`, which returns your custom Sender.